# What statistical test to perform to find differences between groups that has sub-groups?

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis-test

I have this dataset (N = 15k) in which there are 17 main variables and 8 topics. The variables are all continuous while all topics are binary.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(`Column 1` = c(4.6875, 4.35625, 4.62083333333333, 
3.625, 4.125, 4.16666666666667, 4.41071428571429, 3.78125, 4.77083333333333, 
4.90625, 4.75, 3.85, 4, 4.78125, 4.44791666666667, 3.66666666666667, 
3.95833333333333, 4.17916666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.25634920634921
), `Column 2` = c(4.16666666666667, 4.2, 3.38888888888889, 4, 
3.33333333333333, 4.06666666666667, 3.87857142857143, 3.38888888888889, 
4.75, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.58333333333333, 
4.34722222222222, 5, 2.77777777777778, 2.8, 3.54166666666667, 
3.86666666666667, 3.83888888888889), `Column 3` = c(4.42857142857143, 
4.2952380952381, 4.57619047619048, 3.64285714285714, 4, 4.26190476190476, 
3.6421768707483, 3.17857142857143, 4.76190476190476, 4.58333333333333, 
4.85714285714286, 4.22857142857143, 4.14285714285714, 4.53571428571429, 
4.31666666666667, 3.71428571428571, 4.09523809523809, 3.48571428571429, 
4.19047619047619, 3.83741496598639), `Column 4` = c(4.375, 4.43333333333333, 
4.375, 3.5, 3.75, 4.08333333333333, 4.30952380952381, 3.25, 5, 
4.9375, 4.875, 3.88333333333333, 4.25, 4.4375, 4.27083333333333, 
3.58333333333333, 3.625, 3.275, 4.08333333333333, 4.05), `Column 5` = c(5, 
4.27777777777778, 4.44444444444444, 3.5, 4.5, 3.77777777777778, 
4.38095238095238, 4.16666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.91666666666667, 
5, 4.13333333333333, 4.55555555555556, 4.66666666666667, 4.65, 
4.33333333333333, 4.44444444444444, 3.26666666666667, 4.77777777777778, 
4.3), `Column 6` = c(4.33333333333333, 4.5, 4.52222222222222, 
4, 3.83333333333333, 4, 4.52380952380952, 4.16666666666667, 4.55555555555556, 
4.91666666666667, 4.36111111111111, 4, 4, 4.91666666666667, 4.41666666666667, 
4, 3.33333333333333, 4.08333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.06666666666667
), `Column 7` = c(4.11538461538461, 4.18461538461538, 4.46153846153846, 
3.92307692307692, 3.72727272727273, 4.11666666666667, 3.68131868131868, 
3.55128205128205, 4.70512820512821, 4.71153846153846, 4.69871794871795, 
3.93333333333333, 4, 4.61538461538461, 4.37121212121212, 3.75925925925926, 
3.80555555555556, 3.70512820512821, 4.43589743589744, 4.01813186813187
), `Column 8` = c(4, 4.05833333333333, 4.70833333333333, 3.875, 
4.25, 4.16666666666667, 3.96428571428571, 2.9375, 4.70833333333333, 
4.6875, 4.875, 3.8375, 4.33333333333333, 4.1875, 4.6, 4.16666666666667, 
3.58333333333333, 3.5625, 4.16666666666667, 3.96706349206349), 
    `Column 9` = c(4.4, 4.33333333333333, 4.6, 4.1, 3.8, 4.06666666666667, 
    4.37142857142857, 3.9, 4.73333333333333, 4.9, 4.75, 4.28, 
    4.06666666666667, 4.75, 4.56, 3.4, 3.26666666666667, 3.56, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.00444444444444), `Column 10` = c(4, 4.22777777777778, 
    4.45555555555556, 3.7, 3.8, 4, 4.26587301587302, 3.91666666666667, 
    4.94444444444444, 4.79166666666667, 4.81944444444444, 3.7, 
    4.11111111111111, 4.61111111111111, 4.88888888888889, 4.25, 
    4.25, 4.08888888888889, 4.19444444444444, 4.43234126984127
    ), `Column 11` = c(4.33333333333333, 4.05555555555556, 4.5, 
    4.16666666666667, 3.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.71428571428571, 
    3.83333333333333, 4.77777777777778, 4.91666666666667, 4.5, 
    3.9, 3.88888888888889, 4.75, 4.6, 3.22222222222222, 3.44444444444444, 
    3.8, 4.33333333333333, 4.11666666666667), `Column 12` = c(4.16666666666667, 
    4.27777777777778, 4.5, 3.25, 4.5, 3.83333333333333, 4, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.61111111111111, 4.66666666666667, 4.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 
    3.88888888888889, 4.36111111111111, 4.13888888888889, 4, 
    4.88888888888889, 3.91666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.005291005291
    ), `Column 13` = c(4.22222222222222, 4.27777777777778, 4.43518518518519, 
    4.05555555555556, 4.125, 4.31481481481481, 3.63227513227513, 
    3.58333333333333, 4.88888888888889, 4.72222222222222, 4.84259259259259, 
    4.07777777777778, 4.2962962962963, 4.69444444444444, 4.40625, 
    3.97916666666667, 4.11111111111111, 3.825, 4.31481481481481, 
    4.08086419753086), `Column 14` = c(4.11111111111111, 4.22962962962963, 
    4.3, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4.07407407407407, 
    3.94179894179894, 3.80555555555556, 4.88888888888889, 4.69444444444444, 
    4.75925925925926, 3.80740740740741, 3.98148148148148, 4.72222222222222, 
    4.5, 3.66666666666667, 3.35185185185185, 3.82592592592593, 
    4.22222222222222, 4.18302469135802), `Column 15` = c(4.125, 
    4.55833333333333, 4.59166666666667, 4, 4.25, 4, 4.39285714285714, 
    4, 5, 4.9375, 4.9375, 4.35833333333333, 4.16666666666667, 
    4.9375, 5, 4.45833333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.75, 4.75, 
    4.52916666666667), `Column 16` = c(4.21428571428571, 4.31428571428571, 
    4.5047619047619, 3.85714285714286, 4.08333333333333, 4.26190476190476, 
    3.90068027210884, 3.53571428571429, 4.90476190476191, 4.89285714285714, 
    4.89285714285714, 3.87222222222222, 4.33333333333333, 4.71428571428571, 
    4.61944444444444, 4.25, 4.14285714285714, 3.51111111111111, 
    4.23809523809524, 4.28174603174603), `Column 17` = c(NaN, 
    1.02777777777778, NaN, 1.17142857142857, 2.07142857142857, 
    1.52777777777778, 1.11111111111111, 1.27777777777778, NaN, 
    1, 1.11428571428571, 1.32258064516129, 1.78125, 1.52777777777778, 
    1.69444444444444, 2.05714285714286, 1.48571428571429, 2.22222222222222, 
    NaN, 1.38235294117647), `Topic 1` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Topic 2` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), 
    `Topic 3` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1), `Topic 4` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `Topic 5` = c(1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), `Topic 6` = c(1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
    `Topic 7` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Topic 8` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I only selected 20 rows for simplicity

```
Rows: 20
Columns: 25
$ `Column 1`  <dbl> 4.687500, 4.356250, 4.620833, 3.625000, 4.125000, 4.166667, 4.410714,...
$ `Column 2`  <dbl> 4.166667, 4.200000, 3.388889, 4.000000, 3.333333, 4.066667, 3.878571,...
$ `Column 3`  <dbl> 4.428571, 4.295238, 4.576190, 3.642857, 4.000000, 4.261905, 3.642177,...
$ `Column 4`  <dbl> 4.375000, 4.433333, 4.375000, 3.500000, 3.750000, 4.083333, 4.309524,...
$ `Column 5`  <dbl> 5.000000, 4.277778, 4.444444, 3.500000, 4.500000, 3.777778, 4.380952,...
$ `Column 6`  <dbl> 4.333333, 4.500000, 4.522222, 4.000000, 3.833333, 4.000000, 4.523810,...
$ `Column 7`  <dbl> 4.115385, 4.184615, 4.461538, 3.923077, 3.727273, 4.116667, 3.681319,...
$ `Column 8`  <dbl> 4.000000, 4.058333, 4.708333, 3.875000, 4.250000, 4.166667, 3.964286,...
$ `Column 9`  <dbl> 4.400000, 4.333333, 4.600000, 4.100000, 3.800000, 4.066667, 4.371429,...
$ `Column 10` <dbl> 4.000000, 4.227778, 4.455556, 3.700000, 3.800000, 4.000000, 4.265873,...
$ `Column 11` <dbl> 4.333333, 4.055556, 4.500000, 4.166667, 3.833333, 4.333333, 4.714286,...
$ `Column 12` <dbl> 4.166667, 4.277778, 4.500000, 3.250000, 4.500000, 3.833333, 4.000000,...
$ `Column 13` <dbl> 4.222222, 4.277778, 4.435185, 4.055556, 4.125000, 4.314815, 3.632275,...
$ `Column 14` <dbl> 4.111111, 4.229630, 4.300000, 3.833333, 3.833333, 4.074074, 3.941799,...
$ `Column 15` <dbl> 4.125000, 4.558333, 4.591667, 4.000000, 4.250000, 4.000000, 4.392857,...
$ `Column 16` <dbl> 4.214286, 4.314286, 4.504762, 3.857143, 4.083333, 4.261905, 3.900680,...
$ `Column 17` <dbl> NaN, 1.027778, NaN, 1.171429, 2.071429, 1.527778, 1.111111, 1.277778,...
$ `Topic 1`   <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ `Topic 2`   <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ `Topic 3`   <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1
$ `Topic 4`   <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ `Topic 5`   <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
$ `Topic 6`   <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
$ `Topic 7`   <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ `Topic 8`   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

I need to perform the statistical test for this such but I'm not sure which one and how to do. This is what I've done so far.

[image]

I used `tableone` package in R to create this table. What seems to me is that the p-value is obtained using `kruskal-wallis` test across all strata? i.e. topic and state both. This doesn't seem like a good way to test the difference between the groups. What can I do? I'm thinking the following two things, but not sure whether this makes sense or not.

1. Kruskal-wallis for topics disregarding the sub-groups
2. wilcox-test for states for each topic?

Can I do those or is there a better way to perform the statistical test?

Comment: What is your research question ?

Comment: That's the right question. I got it

Comment: Can you enlighten us ?

Comment: oh, I meant exactly what you said. I was only looking at it as in "what could I do" not what I should ask. Your question spark that for me (that's what happens when you're novice). The both question that I put in the bullets are valid questions but the research question is the one that I should be focused on. my research question is - "is there a difference between low and high topic". so bullet2. However, how do I choose wilcox vs kruskal.wallis test? I'm trying to read the differences now. I think kruskal.wallis is correct since wilcox is paired, rigth?